# npm fails trying to install node-inspector

Tags: node.js, npm, node-inspector

I am trying to use:

```
npm install -g node-inspector
```

it fails with

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Can someone suggest what I have done wrong?

Comment: what happens when you install it normally, instead of globally?

Comment: which version of node and npm are you using? (have you filed this on the node-inspected issue tracker too, btw?)

Comment: 2014 and still having this same problem... nobody solved it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the --python option to use a different version of Python when installing a module:

npm install node-inspector@0.7.4 -g --python=C:\Python27\python.exe

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in some versions of NPM that was later fixed in [this](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/commit/66dcf0b2b6c4c0f7c3c0d6f610c8d60b393036f2) commit. A workaround is to call `npm cache clear` before installing modules, otherwise you should just update NPM.

Comment: Did "npm cache clear" but it didn't help. Tried repairing the node installation too. Its only a problem on node-inspector. Maybe that's the problem. I was trying to reinstall node-inspector because of another problem I am having.

Comment: I have the today version and still doesn't work. Even tried npm cache clear and doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution:

- Grab last version from https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/releases
- Unzip the folder in your npm global modules, in my case is: "C:\Users\Totty.js\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\"
- Create a file in "C:\Users\Totty.js\AppData\Roaming\npm\" named "node-inspector.cmd" and fill it with this data:

  @IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
    "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\node-inspector\bin\inspector.js" %*
  ) ELSE (
    node  "%~dp0\node_modules\node-inspector\bin\inspector.js" %*
  )
- Cd into the node-inspector folder "C:\Users\Totty.js\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-inspector" and run `npm install`. It should install all the deps of node-inspector.
- Run `node-inspector` now works!